# How to create editable combobox with database?

Tags: java, database, combobox

I am new to java and want to create an editable combobox in which when user types in it the results come from database.

Like if I type "e" in combobox then all the name starting with "e" should come from database.

Please give a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugins, following example is for php just replace the php parts with java code, or have a look at [this](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/autocomplete-in-java-web-application-using-jquery-and-json/).

**With JSON**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
                $("#search").autocomplete({     
                source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                        url : "SearchController",
                        type : "GET",
                        data : {
                                term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(data) {
                                response(data);
                        }
                });
        }
});
});
});
```

**With DB**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
function log( message ) {
$( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
$( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.php",
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="birds">Birds: </label>
<input id="birds">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
Result:
<div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```